# Reducing the space equally when resizing browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When resizing the browser window the browser just reduces the space after the element. I want to decrease the space equally on the left and right as it is done in Facebook.

Here is my code

CSS:

```
body{
     margin-left:10%;
     margin-right:10%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
Some content
.
.
.
.
</body>
```

First I thought of giving a `min-width` to body. But computers having less screen size will be a problem. Also `min-width` will not be good solution.

Comment: The body shouldn't have a margin, as there would be not visible element left, to hold the background, when you shrink the body (by increasing it's margins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give width `80%` to your `body` and give `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` for center aligning

```
   body{
      margin:0 auto;
      width:80%;
    }
```

**suggestion:**

To give styles to body is not a good practice, give styles to top parent div in your page

like this,

```
<body>
<div class="container">
       all page elements.....
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
container{
          margin:0 auto;
          width:80%;
        }
```

Comment: If your problem solved, please click the accepted answer, For Users t know which is correct answer... @harikrishnan.n0077

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered media queries?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

here's a demo:
http://playground.johanbrook.com/css/mediaquerydebug.html

and another good article: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with

```
width: 50em;
max-width: 95%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

as it is suggested so many times on the web to display a centered wrapper, that shrinks and expands with the browser window and equal spaces left and right…